# Angular SEO service updateTag type not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, service, seo

i'm trying to create an seo service based on Angular's Meta service (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta)

one of the methods in the service is social media tags manager.
for some reason it keeps failing with this message:

> Argument of type '{ name: string; content: string; property?:
> undefined; } | { property: string; content: string; name?: undefined;
> }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MetaDefinition'.   Type '{
> name: string; content: string; property?: undefined; }' is not
> assignable to type 'MetaDefinition'.
> Type '{ name: string; content: string; property?: undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ [prop: string]: string; }'.
> Property 'property' is incompatible with index signature.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'

here is the method syntax:

```
  socialTags(action:string,pageTagContent:PageTagContent) {

      
      const socialTags =[
        {name:"twitter:title", content: pageTagContent.pageTitle},
        {name:"twitter:description", content: pageTagContent.description},
        {name:"twitter:image", content: pageTagContent.image},
        {name:"twitter:card", content: pageTagContent.imageLarge},
        {property:'og:title', content: pageTagContent.pageTitle},
        {property:'og:image', content: pageTagContent.image}
      ]

      if(action === 'update'){
        socialTags.forEach( obj => this.meta.updateTag( obj ) ) //obj throws the error
      }else{
       //something else
      }

    }
```

i've based the service on this tutorial:
https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/meta-service-in-angular-add-update-meta-tags-example/

not sure why actually.

Answer (score 0):

ok so after a while I've managed to come up with an idea,
obviously it's a type issue. but where!?
none of the tutorials are even mentioning the types is the context of the updateTag method, so i had to go and dig in the source code...

```
socialTags(action:string,pageTagContent:PageTagContent) {

  //there is more to this subject, also apple meta tags... more og (facebook) tags...
  const socialTags:**MetaDefinition[]** =[
    {name:"twitter:title", content: pageTagContent.pageTitle},
    {name:"twitter:description", content: pageTagContent.description},
    {name:"twitter:image", content: pageTagContent.image},
    {name:"twitter:card", content: pageTagContent.imageLarge},
    {property:'og:title', content: pageTagContent.pageTitle},
    {property:'og:image', content: pageTagContent.image}
    // { property:"og:type", content:"video.movie" },
    // { property:"og:url", content:"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" }, ...
  ]

  if(action === 'update'){
    socialTags.forEach( obj => this.meta.updateTag( obj ) )
  }else{
    this.meta.addTags(socialTags)
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the issue lies in TypeScript's type inference for the updateTag method of Angular's Meta service. The method expects a parameter of type MetaDefinition, which is essentially an object with a key-value pair where both the key and value are strings.

In your case, the socialTags array has items with a union type { name: string; content: string; property?: undefined; } | { property: string; content: string; name?: undefined; }. TypeScript is having trouble determining that each object in the array satisfies the MetaDefinition type.

To resolve this, you can explicitly type the socialTags array and ensure that each object conforms to the MetaDefinition type. Here's how you can do it:

```
const socialTags: MetaDefinition[] = [
  

const socialTags: MetaDefinition[] = [
  { name: "twitter:title", content: pageTagContent.pageTitle },
  { name: "twitter:description", content: pageTagContent.description },
  { name: "twitter:image", content: pageTagContent.image },
  { name: "twitter:card", content: pageTagContent.imageLarge },
  { property: 'og:title', content: pageTagContent.pageTitle },
  { property: 'og:image', content: pageTagContent.image }
];

if (action === 'update') {
  socialTags.forEach(obj => this.meta.updateTag(obj));
} else {
  // something else
}
```

The insights shared in this thread about [keyword rank checker](https://www.reddit.com/r/whataboutseo/comments/1akd4vy/best_keyword_rank_checker/) are invaluable. The recommendations are not only diverse but come with real-world success stories, offering a holistic understanding of each tool's potential. It's a fantastic resource for anyone looking to up their SEO game.